# Create table from combinations in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, combinations

I'm looking for a way to combine these values into different columns in Excel:
I have this table of users (in this example we only have 3 users, but could be up to 5 users):

| users |
| --- |
| angel |
| luis |
| kevin |

What I need to do, is combine those names into 3 different columns (of course using an Excel formula or script), and at the end look like this:

| projects | oncall | operations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| angel | kevin | luis |
| angel | luis | kevin |
| luis | angel | kevin |
| luis | kevin | angel |
| kevin | luis | angel |
| kevin | angel | luis |
| angel | kevin | luis |
| angel | luis | kevin |
| luis | angel | kevin |
| luis | kevin | angel |
| kevin | luis | angel |
| kevin | angel | luis |
| etc.. | etc.. | etc.. |

So, you can see that the users repeat the same amount of time in each column, example: look at the name "kevin", it appears 4 times in the column "operations", as well as luis and angel, the combination is really accurate.

The "projects" column **must always** repeat the same user 2 times, the "oncall" column **must never** repeat the user 2 times, and the operations column doesn't really matter, Here is another example, in this case with 4 users:

| users |
| --- |
| kath |
| mary |
| yen |
| isa |

| projects | oncall | operations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| kath | mary | yen & isa |
| kath | isa | mary & yen |
| mary | kath | yen & isa |
| mary | yen | kath & isa |
| yen | mary | kath & isa |
| yen | isa | kath & mary |
| isa | kath | mary & yen |
| isa | yen | kath & mary |
| kath | mary | yen & isa |
| kath | isa | mary & yen |
| mary | kath | yen & isa |
| mary | yen | kath & isa |
| yen | mary | kath & isa |
| yen | isa | kath & mary |
| isa | kath | mary & yen |
| isa | yen | kath & mary |

There can **only** be 1 user assigned to projects and to oncall, operations can have more than 1 user.
Hope I made myself clear, any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: So you do not want every combination, but only 2 projects per person and repeat it?

Comment: correct, I need to combine 2 projects per person, with the oncall and operations columns

Comment: Then vba will probably be your best bet.  formulas are going to be complicated.

Comment: yeah, a formula or vba programming is fine to me, any help is useful

Comment: Power query would be able to do this quite easily. Something along the lines of this https://gorilla.bi/power-query/create-unique-combinations would give you every combination of your lists